# Moving object from one postion to another in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code here ,i am trying to move an object from one position to another ,on mouse click  ,but everytime i run it it justs instantiate the projectile object in a specific position while it had to instantiate it in a the ffor object position

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject projectile;
    public GameObject foot;
    public GameObject mouse;
    void Start()
    {


    }
    void Update()
        {        
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Vector2 Target = Input.mousePosition;
                Vector2 pos1 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Target);
                GameObject newObj = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(projectile);
                Vector2 pos2 = foot.transform.position;
                transform.position=Vector2.Lerp(pos2,pos1,Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here, I'll address them one at a time. First, the code for moving the projectile is wired up wrong:

```
transform.position=Vector2.Lerp(pos2,pos1,Time.deltaTime);
```

You are moving the object that "Shoot" is attached to, not the new game object (newObj, as you have named it.)

Second, it's important to understand the Update pattern and how to properly use it. Update is run every frame. Time.deltaTime is how much time has passed between the last frame render and this one. This number is usually very small. Lastly, Input.GetMouseButtonDown is true only on the first frame that the mouse is pressed.

The current code you have only attempts to (but fails, due to other code problems) move the projectile the one frame the mouse is clicked. What we want is the mouse click to spawn a projectile, and the projectile to move forward EVERY update.

This will be best accomplished with two classes. I will call them Gun and SeekerBullet. The Gun class will be responsible for creating a bullet every time the mouse button is pressed. The SeekerBullet class will be responsible for moving the bullet to it's target.

**Gun**

```
public SeekerBullet ProjectilePrefab; 

void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         Vector2 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         FireBullet(target);
     }
}

void FireBullet(Vector2 target)
{
    GameObject projectile = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(ProjectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.Identity);
    projectile.GetComponent<SeekerBullet>().Target = target;
}
```

**SeekerBullet**

```
public float MoveSpeed = 5;    
public Vector2 Target { get; set; }

public void Update()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Target, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == Target)
        OnReachTarget();
}

void OnReachTarget()
{
    // Do whatever you want here
    Destroy(gameObject); // delete this seekerbullet
}
```

The main Idea I'm trying to stress is isolating your code to perform it's one function well. The gun shouldn't be responsible for moving the projectile, just creating it and telling it where to go.

Also, note that the projectile is starting wherever the Gun is. See this line

```
GameObject projectile = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(ProjectilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.Identity);
```

The transform.position is the position of the gun object. If you want it to start at the foot, like you have in your code, you can re-implement that just like you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Raycast`. It's pretty simple. Here's an example (Moves the object (transform) in the direction and distance of translation.):

```
  var obj:Transform;
  var hit:RaycastHit;
  var move: boolean = false;
  var moveSpeed:float;
  var moveTime:float;
  private var startTime:float;

  function Update ()
  {
   if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1"))
    {
      var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);


         if (Physics.Raycast (ray, hit, 10000)){
            move = true;
            startTime = Time.time;

           }
       }  

if(move){
    var curTime = Time.time;
    var elapsedTime = curTime - startTime;
    var amountToMove = elapsedTime / moveTime;
    print(amountToMove);
    obj.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(obj.transform.position, hit.point, amountToMove);
    if(obj.transform.position == hit.point){
        move = false;
    }
```

This code creates a plane, and a cube. Assign the above code to the plane, assign the cube to the obj var in the inspector. Click on the plane, and watch the fun.

Comment: It's only making it worst

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. You can use the Vector3.Lerp function to achieve this. Use raycasting to get the mouse click position or the touch position. Then use the initial and the final position in the lerp function. The initial position being the position that the gameobject is at now and the final position being the click / touch position.
You can find the article by The Game Contriver on the same here

[Move to Touch / Click Position - The Game Contriver](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/10/move-to-mouse-click-touch-position-unity.html)